# JQuery append element before list-divider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a web app which creates a list based on what users select (a bit like a shopping list).

Lets say we have the list below already created, then user wants to add "Grapes". I want grapes to be added at the end of the fruits.

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="listOfThings">
    <li data-role="list-divider" id="fruit">Fruit</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="apple" class="addBtn">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="orange" class="addBtn">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="banana" class="addBtn">Banana</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">Vegetables</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="carrot" class="addBtn">Carrot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="celery" class="addBtn">Celery</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code I have at the moment only adds the new item at the end of the list, rather than within the correct list-divider heading.

```
var newItemToAdd = "<li><a href='#' id='grapes' class="addBtn">Grapes</a></li>";

$("#listOfThings .ui-last-child").after($newItemToAdd);
```

(I've just thrown this code together based loosely on my actual project, so don't worrk about the full jQuery code. My question ultimately comes down to: How can I add a new list item at the end of a section, before the next list-divider?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on new information of what you require, I'd suggest you do a proper grouping of the types of entries in the list using classes (since `<ul>`s don't have any way of grouping `<li>`s). The idea is to mark every 'fruit' entry with class .fruit-item, and every vegetable entry with class .vegetable-item, and that way you can come up with a selector that works. e.g `$('li.fruit-item:last')`. See new code below:

```js
var newItemToAdd = "<li><a href='#' id='grapes' class='addBtn'>Grapes</a></li>";

$("li.fruit-item:last").after(newItemToAdd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul data-role="listview" id="listOfThings">
    <li data-role="list-divider" id="fruit">Fruit</li>
    <li class="fruit-item"><a href="#" id="apple" class="addBtn">Apple</a></li>
    <li class="fruit-item"><a href="#" id="orange" class="addBtn">Orange</a></li>
    <li class="fruit-item"><a href="#" id="banana" class="addBtn">Banana</a></li>
    <li class="list-divider" data-role="list-divider">Vegetables</li>
    <li class="vegetable-item"><a href="#" id="carrot" class="addBtn">Carrot</a></li>
    <li class="vegetable-item"><a href="#" id="celery" class="addBtn">Celery</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use jquery's `before()`:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the
>   set of matched elements.

```
$('.list-divider').before(newItemToAdd);
```

Source: [Jquery's before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

---

Also, `.ui-last-child` is a class name and not using psuedo elements correctly. I think your intent was `ul li:last-child`

---

Finally, if you know enough to add a random "divider" class, maybe you can simply add a data-attribute that specifies if its a fruit (lets say `data-type="fruit"`), vegetable, etc.. In which case you can do:

```
$("[data-type='fruit']:last-child").after($newItemToAdd);
```

---

**Important**: In addition to all of that, in your following variable, you have double quotes around your class name while your variable is defined in double-quotes. It should be single quotes like the rest of the attributes.

**Currently:**

```
var newItemToAdd = "<li><a href='#' id='grapes' class="addBtn">Grapes</a></li>";
```

**The class name should be:**

`class='addBtn'` **NOT** `class="addBtn"`

Comment: Thanks Derek. My list dividers do contain a unique data- value. So your suggestion of `$("[data-type='fruit']:last-child").after($newItemToAdd);` is promising, but theyre not children, they're siblings. We also need to be careful of just using :before or :after as there are more than just "fruit" and "vegetable categories. Eg. imagine if there were 3 categories, I may need to add an item to the end of the first section OR the end of the second section OR the end of the last section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify which role the new addition should be placed  Then you can append to that list.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector will not match anything, based on the html you provided. Add a class to your list-divider, and do a `before()`

```js
var newItemToAdd = "<li><a href='#' id='grapes' class='addBtn'>Grapes</a></li>";

$(".list-divider").before(newItemToAdd);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul data-role="listview" id="listOfThings">
    <li data-role="list-divider" id="fruit">Fruit</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="apple" class="addBtn">Apple</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="orange" class="addBtn">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="banana" class="addBtn">Banana</a></li>
    <li class="list-divider" data-role="list-divider">Vegetables</li>
    <li><a href="#" id="carrot" class="addBtn">Carrot</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="celery" class="addBtn">Celery</a></li>
</ul>
```

OR if you don't want to change the html, change the above javascript to this:

```
$("li[data-role='list-divider']").before(newItemToAdd);
```

Further reading: [jQuery .before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Kennasoft, but there's more than one list-divider (each with a unique data- value) but I wont know the order of them so I cant use .before.

Comment: I just noticed that. Let me try to answer based on you comment on @Derek Story's excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var div = $("[data-role='list-divider']:contains('Vegetables')")[0];
$('<li><a href="#" id="banana" class="addBtn">Users Fruit</a></li>').prependTo(divs);
```

Comment: Thanks Nahush, I can't use prepend as I won't know what the following list-divider is (or even if there is one!)